# Excel `Data Levels` Format in Million without Decimal Values - Macbook

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula, format, decimal

I am using Microsoft Powerpoint in a Macbook and In the `Data Levels` in a Chart, I am trying to show the numbers in `Millions`.

I am using the below `Format Code` -

```
# ##0,00   "M"
```

Somehow it is returning me a decimal value

Current Output
`287,32 M`

Target Output

```
287 M
```

I have searched everywhere how to make the right `Format Code`, and tried everything the Internet says in my Macbook.

Do anyone knows how to solve this issue and also is it connected to the Macbook environment somehow or not!

Comment: I do not see a difference in the two.

Comment: Sorry typo, updated again

Comment: try `# ##0   "M"`

Comment: i get the output of 2873 399 M

Comment: What is the actual value in the cell, what is in the formula bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution,

Try this `Format Code`

```
# ##0,00   "M"
```